# Adding Full Text Search via command line

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-core

I'm trying to add the full-text search to sql server via command line since we got a core-server.

I already searched the web but all I get is adding it with GUI or re-installing the complete SQL-instance. 
Anybody got any idea how to do? (Hope it's on-topic, sorry otherwise: I'm not a DBA, where should I ask?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the GUI version of setup to create a `ConfigurationFile.ini` that can be used to run the [command-line setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt) to add the necessary Full Text Search components to an installation of SQL Server Core.

The contents of the ini file, which would need to be modified for your scenario, include `QUIET="True"` which prevents `setup.exe` from displaying a Graphical User Interface.

Modify the below items for your needs, then save the file as `ConfigurationFile.ini` in a location where you can refer to it when running `setup.exe` on the core server.

```
;SQL Server 2012 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter. 
ACTION="Install"

; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined yet. 
ENU="True"

; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI,AutoAdvance for a simplied UI, and EnableUIOnServerCore for bypassing Server Core setup GUI block. 
UIMODE="Normal"

; Setup will not display any user interface. 
QUIET="True"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 
QUIETSIMPLE="False"

; Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover and include product updates. The valid values are True and False or 1 and 0. By default SQL Server Setup will include updates that are found. 
UpdateEnabled="False"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online components, SQL Server Data Tools, and other shared components. 
FEATURES=FULLTEXT

; Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path, a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC share. By default SQL Server Setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows Update service through the Window Server Update Services. 
UpdateSource="MU"

; Displays the command line parameters usage 
HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console. 
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system. 
X86="False"

; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after shared components are already installed. 
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after WOW64 shared components are already installed. 
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 
SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 
ERRORREPORTING="False"

; Specify the installation directory. 
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Add description of input argument FTSVCACCOUNT 
FTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$INSTANCE"
```

An example command-line might be:

```
setup.exe /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE configurationfile.ini
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file for details about the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up full-text search is a *job* for your system's DBA. When you say you're not a DBA, is there someone else who is a DBA, or are you the *acting* DBA? You'll need administrator access to SQL Server to get all this set up.

Let's assume you're the acting DBA, at least.

1. If the full-text components are not installed, they will need to be. This should not require reinstalling your SQL instance from scratch; it should be possible to add them in with the SQL installer. That does assume that your SQL Server edition supports full-text search. I believe there's at least one service that needs to be set up for full-text indexing. The SQL installer should do this for you, but you'll need to double-check and make sure the service is configured to start the way you want it (presumably, automatically).

   *Note*: see [Max Vernon's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187202/116653) answer for help with that on SQL Server Core.
2. Once you have full-text search up and running, you need to create full-text indexes on the columns you want to use full-text search with. The business owners of the system would be the ones to decide which columns these are; the DBA would be the one to identify the actual columns in the system (if needed), and to set up the indexes.
3. Finally, you have to use the full-text [predicates and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search) in your SQL commands to get the benefit of full-text search.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) is the link to MS's documentation on full-text search. The landing page is an overview, but you should be able to find details on the various commands needed in steps 2 and 3 using the left navigation.